# Need validation for creating contiguous array

Tags: c, arrays

I need to create dynamically a 2D contiguous array declared in my code by "`x`" (more precisely declared `double **x` as below) with

```
size of 2D array = [size_tot_y, size_tot_x] = [number of lines, number of columns]
```

Here what I did :

```
  /* 2D Array */
  double **x;
  /* 1D array */
  double *x_vals;

  /* Allocating arrays */
  x = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(*x));
  x_vals = malloc(size_tot_x*size_tot_y*sizeof(*x_vals));

  /* Make x contiguous */
  for (j=0;j<=size_tot_y-1;j++) 
     x[j] = &x_vals[j*size_tot_x];
```

Is this code snippet correct for making `x[i][j]` array contiguous ?

Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: Two different mallocs can return addresses anywhere in memory

Comment: **Note:** `double **x` is a *pointer to pointer to double* and is NOT an *array*. They are two completely different objects in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this code snippet correct for making x[i][j] array contiguous ?

Yes, all data from `x[0][0]` to `x[rows - 1][cols - 1]` are in contiguous areas.

Note that you don't need another pointer for the second `malloc`, I suggest:

```
x = malloc(size_tot_y * sizeof(*x));
x[0] = malloc(size_tot_x * size_tot_y * sizeof(**x));
for (j = 1; j < size_tot_y; j++) 
   x[j] = x[0] + j * size_tot_x;
```

If you are under C99 or C11 you can `malloc` in one step using a pointer to a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```
double (*x)[size_tot_x];

x = malloc(sizeof(double [size_tot_y][size_tot_x]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it gives *seemingly* adjacent memory(*with more space, 8 instead of 4 in the same boat*). You can try my version (tested with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Ubuntu 17.04 and Mac OS X) and your version(tested with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on Ubuntu 17.04 and Mac OS X).

```
// your saying, size of 2D array = 
// [size_tot_y, size_tot_x] = [number of lines, number of columns]

int (*x)[size_tot_y][size_tot_x] = malloc (sizeof(*x));
(*x)[r][c] = something;
...
free(x);
```

***Do you realize the byte differences among the codes?***

Test,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t size_tot_y = 3; //rows
    size_t size_tot_x = 5; //columns

    printf("sizeof(int) = %li\n\n", sizeof(int));

    int (*x)[size_tot_y][size_tot_x] = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    printf("array starts at %p\n", x);
    printf("sizeof(array) = %li\n", sizeof(*x));  // Note the *
    printf("sizeof(array[0][0]) = 0x%lx\n", sizeof((*x)[0][0]));
    puts("");

    size_t r, c;

    for (r = 0; r <= size_tot_y - 1; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c <= size_tot_x - 1; c++) {
            printf("array[%i][%i] is at %p\n", r, c, &((*x)[r][c]));
        };
        puts("");
    };

    free(*x);
}
```

Output of test:

```
sizeof(int) = 4

array starts at 0x5201480
sizeof(array) = 60
sizeof(array[0][0]) = 0x4

array[0][0] is at 0x5201480
array[0][1] is at 0x5201484
array[0][2] is at 0x5201488
array[0][3] is at 0x520148c
array[0][4] is at 0x5201490

array[1][0] is at 0x5201494
array[1][1] is at 0x5201498
array[1][2] is at 0x520149c
array[1][3] is at 0x52014a0
array[1][4] is at 0x52014a4

array[2][0] is at 0x52014a8
array[2][1] is at 0x52014ac
array[2][2] is at 0x52014b0
array[2][3] is at 0x52014b4
array[2][4] is at 0x52014b8

--25548-- REDIR: 0x4ec00e0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ecf0 (free)
==25548== 
==25548== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25548==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25548==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,084 bytes allocated
==25548== 
==25548== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25548== 
==25548== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==25548== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Your version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t size_tot_y = 3; //rows
    size_t size_tot_x = 5; //columns
    size_t i,j;

    /* 2D Array */
    double **x;
    /* 1D array */
    double *x_vals;

    /* Allocating arrays */
    x = malloc(size_tot_y*sizeof(*x));
    x_vals = malloc(size_tot_x*size_tot_y*sizeof(*x_vals));

    /* Make x contiguous */
    for (j=0;j<=size_tot_y-1;j++)
        x[j] = &x_vals[j*size_tot_x];


    printf("array starts at %p\n", x);
    printf("sizeof(array) = %li\n", sizeof(x) * size_tot_x * size_tot_y);
    printf("sizeof(array[0][0]) = 0x%lx\n", sizeof((x)[0][0]));
    puts("");

    size_t r, c;

    for (r = 0; r <= size_tot_y - 1; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c <= size_tot_x - 1; c++) {
            printf("array[%i][%i] is at %p\n", r, c, &((x)[r][c]));
        };
        puts("");
    };
    free((void*) x_vals);
    free((void*) x);

}
```

Your output:

```
array starts at 0x5201040
sizeof(array) = 120
sizeof(array[0][0]) = 0x8

array[0][0] is at 0x52010a0
array[0][1] is at 0x52010a8
array[0][2] is at 0x52010b0
array[0][3] is at 0x52010b8
array[0][4] is at 0x52010c0

array[1][0] is at 0x52010c8
array[1][1] is at 0x52010d0
array[1][2] is at 0x52010d8
array[1][3] is at 0x52010e0
array[1][4] is at 0x52010e8

array[2][0] is at 0x52010f0
array[2][1] is at 0x52010f8
array[2][2] is at 0x5201100
array[2][3] is at 0x5201108
array[2][4] is at 0x5201110

--28481-- REDIR: 0x4ec00e0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ecf0 (free)
==28481== 
==28481== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28481==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28481==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,168 bytes allocated
==28481== 
==28481== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28481== 
==28481== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==28481== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Strange, valgrind tells you 2 allocs and you are calling `malloc` only once in the first snippet, same for the second snippet (2 `malloc`s and valgrind says 3)

Comment: Yes indeed, you of course know C better than me sir. However, it results in as shown. @KeineLust

Comment: _you of course know C better than me sir_: eeing? I'm not criticizing you, your code is correct, valgrind lies (or you are calling valgrind with another program)

Comment: compile again please

Comment: This is really weird